# JavaScript проверить наличие ключа в массиве

Tags: javascript, массивы

я создаю массив данным кодом

```
        function (geocode) {
            if (geocode.status == 'OK') {
                console.log(geocode.results[0].address_components);
                for(var i = 0; i < geocode.results[0].address_components.length ; i++) {
                     arrayAddressData[geocode.results[0].address_components[i].types[0]] = geocode.results[0].address_components[i].short_name;
                }
                console.log(arrayAddressData);
            } else {
                console.log('else');
            }
        }
```

в итоге я получаю такой массив

```
administrative_area_level_1: "MA"
administrative_area_level_2: "Suffolk County"
country: "US"
locality: "Boston"
neighborhood: "Dorchester"
postal_code: "02124"
postal_code_suffix: "2111"
route: "Alpha Rd"
street_number: "11"
```

Мне нужно проверить, есть ли в данном массиве ключи такие как `route`, `street_number`, `route`,`postal_code`, и если есть проверить, включают ли они в себя value, или нет.

Как это можно сделать без цыкла. Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это, наверное, всё-таки объект, а не массив?

```js
const loc = {
  administrative_area_level_1: "MA",
  administrative_area_level_2: "Suffolk County",
  country: "US",
  locality: "Boston",
  neighborhood: "Dorchester",
  postal_code: "02124",
  postal_code_suffix: "2111",
  route: "Alpha Rd",
  street_number: "11"
}

const checkKey = (key, value) => {
  if (key in loc) {
    if (loc[key].indexOf(value) !== -1) {
      return `ключ "${key}" содержит значение "${value}"`;
    }
    return `ключ "${key}" не содержит значение "${value}"`;
  }
  return `ключа "${key}" не существует`;
}

console.log(checkKey('выв', 'dsds'));
console.log(checkKey('route', 'sdsds'));
console.log(checkKey('postal_code', '02124'));
```